# Nothing gets destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Nothing gets destroyed? I have one enemy which is a sphere with a collider and a rigidbody and a cube with the same. I've tried enabling triggers on either one but gravity goes wack and nothing gets destroyed! Please help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyOnCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Is this for a player or for an enemy or what as the code seems to be half and half

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your Script to the Player and to the Enemy GameObjects instead of putting them into one separate Script.

Because OnTriggerEnter and OnCollisionEnter get called on the Object that is colliding or entering the Trigger

You can't just make a universal script that handles all Collision, because that Script or Object isn't colliding with anything. Because of that the functions never gets called and therefore nothing gets destroyed.

**Changed Player Script (Add):**

```
// The Enemey needs to have IsTrigger enabled

 private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
     if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
     {
          Destroy(other.gameObject);
     }
        
  }
```

**Changed Enemy Script (Add):**

```
// Player needs to have IsTrigger disabled

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
}
```